# Cannot exceed 60hz in display settings

Tags: display, nvidia-geforce

Hi Guys I have a decent pc.
A RADEON GTX TI 1070 GFX
A ASUS VG248QE Monitor (supposed to handle 144hz)
And I got them hooked with a DisplayPort(pc) -> HDMI(Monitor)

Settings are 1920x1080p
So I can only get to 60hz, both in the Nvidia Control panel
and in the Native windows 10 monitor settings.

Can someone help me figure out whats wrong?
I should be able to handle more than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the display’s manual, you’ll find the following (partial) table:

[image: resolutions]

As you can see, only Dual-link DVI or DisplayPort support 120/144 Hz operation. You’re using HDMI. You have to use the DisplayPort input on the display.